# wpf how to add different commands to keybindings in a control based on datacontext of item

Tags: wpf, xaml

Originally I added to the input bindings of the actual treeviewitem on the loaded event like this:

```
 void MultiSelectTreeViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.SelectAll, new KeyGesture(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control)));
      SignalViewModel svm = this.DataContext as SignalViewModel;
      if (svm != null)
      {
        this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(DaedalusGraphViewer.GraphViewer.AddSignalsCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.Enter)));
      }
      BitViewModel bvm = this.DataContext as BitViewModel;
      if (bvm != null)
      {
        this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(DaedalusGraphViewer.GraphViewer.OpenNewBusDialogCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.Enter)));
      }
    }
```

the problem with this is that if I want to use the treeviewitem elsewhere and have different commands, I would have to make a new treeviewitem class each time. I am definitely violating MVVM here and coupling too much so I want to fix this old code (been trying to adopt mvvm practices lately, but there is still a lot of old stuff that I didn't do correctly).

What I would like is a way to attach the keybinding in xaml, but I am still a little hazy on what determines whether a keybinding works. is a keybinding only available if the item on which the keybinding exists is in focus? can you access parent keybindings or child keybindings of the currently focused item? Based on my testing it looked like you can't access keybindings from the parent and I read another stackoverflow post that made it seem like you can't access children either. Is that the case?

I just need a nice customizeable way to set keybindings on different tiers of a treeview that is templateable so that I don't have to make new classes every time.

edit:
it occurs to me that one possible solution is to attach the input bindings to the textbox at each tier with a different command for each, then stretch the textbox to fill the item and put the focus on the textbox instead of the treeview. is that the best option? ideally I kind of wish hierarchicaldatatemplate had input bindings or something.